# Assigning a field name from a method to Firestore document

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have a collection called 'users'. When someone clicks the upvote button, I want it to update the user document with an entry that's the slug from the page they are viewing.  However, I'm not sure how to accomplish it using the code I have.

```
voteUp() {
        const voteup_ref = db.collection("builds").doc(this.$route.params.slug)
        const voteuser_ref = db.collection("users").doc(this.alias)
        return db.runTransaction(t => {
          return t.get(voteup_ref).then(doc => {
            const newCount = doc.data().voteup + 1
            const NewSlug = voteuser_ref
            t.update(voteup_ref, {
              voteup: newCount
            })
            t.update(voteuser_ref, {
              NewSlug: 'voteup'
            })
          });
        })
      },
```

So, if someone is viewing a page with the slug of 'my-awesome-comment', I want 'my-awesome-comment' to be entered in the user's document with a value of "voteup".

What's actually happening is that it will write an entry to the user document as I expect, but it's entering the field name as 'NewSlug' with a value of "voteup" instead of whatever the slug actually is.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written the JSON object `NewSlug` itself is the property name, instead of using its value. To do the latter, you need to use square bracket notation (`[]`):

```
let update = {};
update[NewSlug] = 'voteup';
t.update(voteuser_ref, update)
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.  Message is: Transaction.update() called with invalid data. Invalid field path ([object Object]). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'
    at new FirestoreError

Comment: That sounds like `NewSlug` contains characters that are not allowed in a Firestore document ID. You'll have to filter those from your `NewSlug` value. See https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+javascript+filter+some+characters+from+a+string

Comment: The slug only has dashes. I'm thinking it's picking up the brackets on [NewSlug] and complaining about those.

Comment: Nope. the brackets in my notation are plain JavaScript, and are not sent to the server. Check the `JSON.stringify(update)` output if you want to validate that. In fact, that should show you precisely what is being sent, and thus what Firestore complains about.

Comment: Well, then I guess something else is wrong, but I don't know what.  Are you able to put it into context with my existing code?

Comment: Did you print the `update` values as I showed in my previous comment? What was the output?

Comment: Well, my code looks like this, but I don't know if it's correct.   t.update(voteup_ref, { 
              voteup: newCount
            })
            let update = {};
            update[NewSlug] = 'voteup';
            t.update(voteuser_ref, update)                The message I get is [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function Transaction.update() called with invalid data. Invalid field path ([object Object]). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'"

Comment: As you may have noticed, putting significant code in a comment is not very readable. Unless you can show me what `console.log(JSON.stringify(update))` prints, there's not much more I can do. The error message clearly indicates that you have an invalid character in the path/ID, and the `[]` I introduced you to is the normal way to use the value of a variable as a property name.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood you.  Here's what it says: {"[object Object]":"voteup"}

Comment: Ah right, I now see how you initialize `NewSlug`, which is esssentially `const NewSlug = db.collection("users").doc(this.alias)`. That won't work, since a `DocumentReference` is not a valid ID. Were you trying to set it to the [document's path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#path)?

Comment: to the name of the slug in my 'builds' collection, which the page already knows about since it pulled the data from it to show information.  so the intended functionality is to write the name of the 'builds' document title (which is also the builds.slug field) to the 'users' collection, on that user's document.  just a way to keep track of what they upvoted and downvoted.  unless you know of some other elegant way to handle it.